# Handsontable custom object data

Tags: object, handsontable

I am trying to fill a Handsontable with objects.
For example:

```
var data = [
    [{title: 'A1', style: '...'}, {title: 'B1', style: '...'}],
    [{title: 'A2', style: '...'}, {title: 'B2', style: '...'}],
];
```

Now I want that Handsontable only renders the title attribute into the cells and not the style. The style attribute is used to render the cells with special fomatting.
How do I tell Handsontable to only use the title attribute?

Comment: Have you looked at the [object data source with column mapping](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/tutorial-data-sources.html#page-nested) docs? Also, could you provide a fiddle with your example working?

Comment: yes, please look at the documentation, this is a very simple use case which is heavily documented and should be as easy as doing a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [
    [{title: 'A1', style: '...'}, {title: 'B1', style: '...'}],
    [{title: 'A2', style: '...'}, {title: 'B2', style: '...'}],
];

var filterArrays = function (arys) {
    let ret = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let ary = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            ary.push(data[i][j].title);
        }
        ret.push(ary);
    }
    return ret;
}

var titles = filterArrays(data);
```

Here titles could be

```
titles = [
    ['A1', 'B1'],
    ['A2', 'B2']
];
```

So, you can use titles as a data. And styling your cells for each cells please check followings.

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: titles,
    ...
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        cellProperties.renderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            td.style = data[row][col].style;
        };
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

handsontable data is not intended to give style to the cells. To define the cell styles I recommend you wear this link

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/demo-conditional-formatting.html

But if your idea is to have hidden columns , such as a code , I leave this example

```
<script>

var options = {
 columns: CutObject(data)
}

function CutObject(data){
 return data.slice(1);//hide firt column
}

</script>
```